# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm getting a SQL Server error:

> A transport-level error has occurred
>   when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 0 - The handle is
>   invalid.)

I'm running Sql Server 2008 SP1, Windows 2008 Standard 64 bit.

It's a .Net 4.0 web application. It happens when a request is made to the server. It's intermittent. Any idea how I can resolve it?

Comment: database and web server are on same server (Shared Memory). I would suspect a bug in your code...

Comment: I never found the answer. It was random. Once I rebooted the machine it went away and I haven't see the issue again.

Comment: This may occur if the database was created on an older version of SQL Express/MSDE that set AUTO_CLOSE to True. Or the SQL Server service instance was restarted.

Comment: Wow, is there any other way to solve this problem? I'm getting it on a dev server where everyting where still doing fine before last week. Now, it seems that we can make a READ but not an UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE. I need an answer please.

Comment: I had the same issue as @Simon, using the dev web server that devenv fires up.  Could read, but not delete.  Anyway, restarting the server fixed it.  Have only had the problem once in several months.

Comment: @devstuff that's good to know. I cant' remember if it was an older database or not.

Comment: I had the same issue and the restart fixed it on my dev box.  Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue and restarting IIS fixed it.

Comment: Just had the same thing on an ASP.Net web app. I restarted the application pool and it was OK, no need to reboot either box

Comment: On my dev computer, I just shut down the Visual Studio IIS debug server and then restarted the project website. worked.

Comment: I got this error because something went wrong with the session database. Only restarting the web applications that were using it could fix the issue.

Comment: open `cmd.exe`, type `iisreset` - it worked

Comment: i restarted the sql server instance and that fixed it for me

Comment: I tried restarting IIS, restarting the web app, restarting the app pool.  All of them only fixes the problem temporarily (i.e. the problem occurred again in a few hours). I restarted the machine a day ago, and have not seen the problem yet.

Comment: Got the error when doing Import-SPWeb from PowerShell on a SharePoint box. iisreset helped.

Comment: I can be cause by a pending action on your db.
this result in a DB lock.

Comment: The marked answer isn't an answer.  The answer by Michael Olivero below that actually provides content and following it solved the problem when I ran into it.  (Manually closing the temporary web server on my dev machine.)  I recommend the answer be changed.

Comment: I didn't even restart anything to fix it. I just dragged the break point up and reran the code and it worked. I also have a windows service that logs this error occasionally, but it always continues working on it's own after encountering the error once or twice.

Comment: Nothing fixed it for me, except restarting the workstation.

Comment: @Flexo This is closed as off-topic? I just had it happen to me with brand new installs of VS 2017 and MS SQL 2016 Enterprise. While it was working just fine with VS 2015 Community.

Comment: This shouldn't be off-topic. The issue has nothing to do with the code in use, so an MCVE cannot be created for it. Also, the closure reason states: `this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers` - but 179k people have come across this question.

Comment: this may help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64409/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server/316060#316060

Answer (score 126):

The database connection is closed by the database server.  The connection remains valid in the connection pool of your app; as a result, when you pickup the shared connection string and try to execute it's not able to reach the database.  If you are developing Visual Studio, simply close the temporary web server on your task bar.

If it happens in production, resetting your application pool for your web site should recycle the connection pool.

Comment: This one is the actual answer.

Comment: In my particular case, I had a `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` setting in connection string that caused the same error.

Comment: For me running an iisreset command from an elevated command prompt resolved the issue (I was debugging from Visual Studio against IIS)

Comment: I got this error due to SQL Server not liking one of my commented out lines of SQL.
My advice is to start with the simplest code to validate that it is not a connection issue and then work up from there.

The commented out line was --EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp ... for which the remote computer did not have permission to run.
There is an almost identical line later on in the code that was accepted, so I think this is some vague security patch error also.
You would think a commented out line would have no affect on connectivity issues, but here we are.

Answer (score 19):

Try the following command on the command prompt:

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled
```

This turns off the auto scaling abilities of the network stack

Comment: Can you provide some details on what that actually does?  Are there any reasons against setting such a value globally?

Comment: it turns off the auto scaling abilities of the network stack.

Comment: Does not work in Windows XP SP3. Netsh interface does not have tcp sub command in Windows XP, however it works well in Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: I know this is old, but this was the only solution that worked for me (most issues/solutions revolve around a webserver/app, my situation is desktop app and local network server, no IIS or anything like that). Why would turning off autotuning/autoscaling fix this problem?

Comment: It gives me an error **"Set global command failed on IPv4 The parameter is incorrect."**

Comment: in my case, ReOpen of SQL Server Management Studio solved the problem

Comment: This dramatically reduced the number of occurrences, but did not completely eliminate the errors. It went from around 40 down to 2 per hour.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. I restarted Visual Studio and that fixed the problem

Comment: Restarting the PC did the thing for me.

Answer (score 15):

Transport level errors are often linked to the connection to sql server being broken ... usually network.

Timeout Expired is usually thrown when a sql query takes too long to run.

So few options can be :

1. Check for the connection in VPN (if used) or any other tool
2. Restart IIS
3. Restart machine
4. Optimize sql queries.

Answer (score 13):

For those not using IIS, I had this issue when debugging with Visual Studio 2010. I ended all of the debugger processes: WebDev.WebServer40.EXE which solved the issue.

Comment: Please tell the steps to on how you ended those process. I am beginner and I don't know what you mean by "ended all the debugger process"

Comment: @Unbreakable I just used Task Manager. In the task manager, you can see all the running processes with the name WebDev.WebServer40.EXE. See https://betanews.com/2015/10/08/how-to-kill-a-windows-process/ for how to kill a windows process.

Answer (score 7):

All you need is to Stop the ASP.NET Development Server and run the project again

Answer (score 7):

Look at the [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/) which details out this error:

> Removing Connections
>
> The connection pooler removes a connection from the pool after it has
>   been idle for a long time, or if the pooler detects that the
>   connection with the server has been severed.
>
> Note that a severed connection can be detected only after attempting
>   to communicate with the server. If a connection is found that is no
>   longer connected to the server, it is marked as invalid.
>
> Invalid connections are removed from the connection pool only when
>   they are closed or reclaimed.
>
> If a connection exists to a server that has disappeared, this
>   connection can be drawn from the pool even if the connection pooler
>   has not detected the severed connection and marked it as invalid.
>
> This is the case because the overhead of checking that the connection
>   is still valid would eliminate the benefits of having a pooler by
>   causing another round trip to the server to occur.
>
> When this occurs, the first attempt to use the connection will detect
>   that the connection has been severed, and an exception is thrown.
>
> Basically what you are seeing is that exception in the last sentence.
>
> A connection is taken from the connection pool, the application does
>   not know that the physical connection is gone, an attempt to use it is
>   done under the assumption that the physical connection is still there.
>
> And you get your exception.
>
> There are a few common reasons for this.
>
> 1. The server has been restarted, this will close the existing connections.
>
> In this case, have a look at the SQL Server log, usually found at:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL\LOG
>
> If the timestamp for startup is very recent, then we can suspect that
>   this is what caused the error. Try to correlate this timestamp with
>   the time of exception.
>
> 2009-04-16 11:32:15.62 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file
>   ‘C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG’.
>
> 2. Someone or something has killed the SPID that is being used.
>
> Again, take a look in the SQL Server log. If you find a kill, try to
>   correlate this timestamp with the time of exception.
>
> 2009-04-16 11:34:09.57 spidXX      Process ID XX was killed by
>   hostname xxxxx, host process ID XXXX.
>
> 3. There is a failover (in a mirror setup for example) again, take a look in the SQL Server log.
>
> If there is a failover, try to correlate this timestamp with the time
>   of exception.
>
> 2009-04-16 11:35:12.93 spidXX     The mirrored database “” is changing roles from “PRINCIPAL” to “MIRROR” due to
>   Failover.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! This should receive a lot more votes because it actually helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you are connected to your database via Microsoft SQL Server Management, close all your connections and retry.
Had this error when connected to another Azure Database, and worked for me when closed it.
Still don't know why ..

Comment: This was a fix that worked for me.  I shut down SQL Server Management Studio and then I never saw this error again.

Comment: i can't believe it, but this actually worked. I could be that the server was saturated at first moment, who knows. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Was getting this, always after about 5 minutes of operation.  Investigated and found that a warning from e1iexpress always occurred before the failure.  This apparently is an error having to do with certain TCP/IP adapters.  But changing from WiFi to hardwired didn't affect it.

So tried Plan B and restarted Visual Studio.  Then it worked fine.

On closer study I noticed that, when working correctly, the message `The Thread '<No Name>' has exited with code 0` occurred at almost exactly the time the run crashed in previous attempts.  Some Googling reveals that that message comes up when (among other things) the server is trimming the thread pool.

Presumably there was a bogus thread in the thread pool and every time the server attempted to "trim" it it took the app down.

Answer (score 3):

You get this message when your script make SQL Service stopped for some reasons. so if you start SQL Service again perhaps your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Kindly provide steps to on how to start SQL Service. I am a beginner and I just created an asp.net mvc 5 application. and when I run "enable-migrations" everything is fine then I run "add-migration "sdfd" everything is fine and then when I click on update-database I get this error. please guide me

Answer (score 3):

I know this may not help everyone (who knows, maybe yes), but I had the same problem and after some time, we realized that the cause was something out of the code itself.

The computer trying to reach the server, was in another network, the connection could be established but then dropped.

The way we used to fix it, was to add a static route to the computer, allowing direct access to the server without passing thru the firewall.

```
route add –p YourServerNetwork mask NetworkMask Router
```

Sample:

```
route add –p 172.16.12.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.11.2
```

I hope it helps someone, it's better to have this, at least as a clue, so if you face it, you know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in Visual Studion 2012 development environment, stopped the IIS Express and rerun the application, it started working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved it, truncating the SQL Server LOG.
Check doing that, and then tell us, if this solution helped you.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was totally different.

In my case I had an objectsource which required a datetimestamp parameter. Even though that ODS parameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull was true 1/1/0001 was being passed to SelectMethod. That in turn caused a sql datetime overflow exception when that datetime was passed to the sql server.

Added an additional check for datetime.year != 0001 and that solved it for me.

Weird that it would throw a transport level error and not a datetime overflow error.
Anyways..

Comment: there's no way this is related, it must have been coincidental

Answer (score 2):

One of the reason I found for this error is '**Packet Size=xxxxx**' in connection string. if the value of xxxx is too large, we will see this error. Either remove this value and let SQL server handle it or keep it low, depending on the network capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the "SQL Server" Server service stopped. When I restarted the service that enabled me to run the query and eliminate the error.

Its also a good idea to examine your query to find out why the query made this service stop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer is to upgrade the OS from 2008R2 to 2012R2, the solution of iisreset or restart apppool didn't work for me.
I also tried to turn of TCP Chimney Offload setting, but I didn't restart the server because it is a production server, which didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this error recently between our business server and our database server.
The solution for us was to disable "IP Offloading" on the network interfaces.
Then the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I was trying to restore a SQL database and checked following Check Box in `Options` tab,

[image]

As it's a stand alone database server just closing down SSMS and reopening it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when the database is dropped and re-created some shared resources is still considering the database still exists, so when you re-run execute query to create tables in the database after it was re-created the error will not show again and `Command(s) completed successfully.` message will show instead of the error message `Msg 233, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)`.

Simply ignore this error when you are dropping and recreating databases and re-execute your DDL queries with no worries.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently, but i was not able to get answer in google.
So thought of sharing it here, so that it can help someone in future.

Error:

While executing query the query will provide few output then it will throw below error.

> "Transport level error has occurred when receiving output from
>   server(TCP:provider,error:0- specified network name is no longer
>   available"

Solution:

1. Check the provider of that linked server
2. In that provider properties ,Enable "Allow inprocess" option for that particular provider to fix the issue.