# ASP.NET MVC : Using the same database for Entity Framework and ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, sql-server-2008-express, .net-4.0

Im trying to user ASP.NET MVC3 with Entity Framework and ASP.NET Membership for authentication. I've set up an existing database as my application services database for membership.

When i create the entity data model through the wizard it adds the following connection string to my web.config.

```
<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=PM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I'm a noob so i don't really understand why but i tried using the same connection string for my membership provider and failed (probably because of this: providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" ?).

So i added a separate connection string to the same database and used it for the membership provider.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=PM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

It works fine when i use ASP.NET configuration to add user and etc. But when i run the application and try to do something like validating a user i get an error;

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)

I made a guess this has something to do with my connection strings. I'm hoping some of you experts can help. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried restarting the server : [A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962927/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server) ?

Not a solution or an answer, just a pointer to a similar issue..

Comment: Wow it does fix it. Feel silly for wasting a whole question on it thinking it had something to do with my connection strings..

Comment: @qbantek I beg to differ.  It *is* a solution and an answer. Solved my problem. +1