# LINQ to SQL SubmitChanges() not work to insert new record

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, submitchanges

First, I'm pretty new to LINQ to SQL, so this is probably a dumb question, but I'm trying to insert a new record into the database and I keep getting the following error:

```
The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login. Possible causes include the following:  the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server; the server was too busy to accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)
```

I can step through my code and see that all the data is present as I would expect it to, but when it hits the

```
db.SubmitChanges()
```

in the method below I get the error.  What am I doing wrong?  This is SOO frustrating and I've lost a day trying to figure out LINQ to SQL... I'm half tempted to just bag it and go back to using ADO.NET and stored procs.

```
public static void Save(Customer customerToSave)
    {
        IpmDatabaseDataContext db = new IpmDatabaseDataContext();
        db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customerToSave);

        // commit the changes to the db
        db.SubmitChanges();     
    }
```

In my app.config it has this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IPM.Business.Properties.Settings.IPMConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=socrates\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=IPM;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am still on my dev machine, so this is the correct connection string.

Comment: This probably has something to do with the Database setup or connection string (connection pooling, and such). Could you post some more info about that?

Comment: Your LINQ is probably OK. Check database connection (or rebuild the context)

Answer (score 0):

What is the connection string you are passing to `IpmDatabaseDataContext`? The error you are getting isn't related to LINQtoSQL, it's a database connectivity problem.

To debug the problem, try explicitly passing your connection string to the `DataContext` constructor, e.g.:

```
IpmDatabaseDataContext db = new IpmDatabaseDataContext(
    @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true");
```

The following posts suggest that the *Shared Memory Provider ... handle is invalid* error will go away if you **reboot** Windows:

[ASP.NET MVC : Using the same database for Entity Framework and ASP.NET Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782658/asp-net-mvc-using-the-same-database-for-entity-framework-and-asp-net-membershi)

[A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962927/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server)

Comment: In my app.config it has this connection string: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="IPM.Business.Properties.Settings.IPMConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=socrates\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=IPM;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work.  I got the same error.

   IpmDatabaseDataContext db = new IpmDatabaseDataContext(@"server=socrates\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=IPM");

Comment: Do you get the same "Shared Memory Provider ... handle is invalid" error when doing a normal ADO (non-LINQtoSQL) INSERT on the same table, same database, in the same project?

Comment: explicitly passing your connection string should work.if not plz check your connection string again.