# A transport-level error has occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962927/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server)

> A transport-level error has occurred
>   when sending the request to the
>   server. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on
>   the other end of the pipe.)

We are getting the following error message appearing intermittently on our server. We are running a asp.net 4 web application with SQL Server 2008 database. Has anyone ever come across this error message and a solution to stop this happening.

The strange thing is this issue was not occurring on our dev system and we are finding it very difficult to replicate due to the sporadic nature of this issue.

**Still have not found a solution to this issue.**

Comment: This error will also occur if someone (e.g. a DBA or some server process) kills the connection.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the error message indicates, there is a connectivity problem with a previously opened session in SQL Server.

Try:

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

---

[SqlConnection.ClearAllPools Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools.aspx) resets (or empties) the connection pool. If there are connections in use at the time of the call, they are marked appropriately and will be discarded (instead of being returned to the pool) when Close is called on them.

Comment: yeah i've had this before when i delete a dev database while the website is running and recreate it and forget to restart the website and the website is using the old sql session

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have a few times actually. Very very irratating error.
If I'm not mistaken had something to do with Named Pipes instead of Shared Memory being used.

Please take a look at the following links should help you sort out the isse.

[Link 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host.aspx)
[Link 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/9609559d-f7ce-4bd8-97d0-0003ff7c9c98/)

Comment: Thanks @jethro I looked at the web.config file and we are making use of 'localhost' I think i might give '(local)' a try to see if this makes any difference.

Comment: No, you actually have to look at sql server. Go to SQL Server = > Configuration Tools => Sql server configuration Manger and you need to look at what sql is using there.