# Migrating database from SQL Server 2005 to 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, windows-xp, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012

Apologies for the vague question but I am having some trouble

I am in progress of migrating databases from SQL Server 2005 (running on XP) to 2012 (running on server 2012) and have hit some trouble. I have unmounted from 2005 and then re-mounted in 2012. I ran the only stored procedure associated with the database on the 2012 box and it fails with the following error

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)

If I run the stored procedure on 2005 it works fine and is done in 10 seconds.

Is there anything I should consider before I move the databases.

If you need more info please ask, I didn't display the stored procedure here because I believe its not to do with the stored procedure.

Comment: Migrating from 2005 to 2012 shouldn't directly cause this problem. Check out the solution from [A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962927/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server)

Comment: its very strange, if I log onto the sql server 2012 box via remote desktop and run the query it fails.

If I run remotely from my PC use management studio it works.

Comment: Did you try the fixes mentioned in the link (restarting SQL, restarting IIS, restarting Windows...)?