# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting this error when debugging using Visual Studio 2013 and local IIS 8. I'm using Entity Framework and the database is not local, it's on a remote Windows Server 2012 running SQL Server 2012

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)

The odd thing is that this doesn't happen when you try to load the website normally, when I'm debugging with Visual Studio (debugging local not remote code) and using the remote testing DB on the same server. I get this error

It executes the first query and gets results, when it executes another one the error occurs. I've searched for hours, tried everything I could find but nothing's working. The other odd thing is that it was working fine just a week ago! I hadn't worked on the project for a week and it was working when I left, I came back and this started happening. I kept looking through the server for any changes, nothing is different. I've never encountered this error before, it just started happening without any changes to the code. The same code runs fine on the server, this error seems to happen only when I'm using Visual Studio or IIS 8 on my machine

Here is the stack trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) +3278660
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +791
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error) +697
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync() +224
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket() +126
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer() +101
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value) +46
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +658
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +92
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +102
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +552
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +3114
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +554
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +98
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +307
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +474
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +667
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +932
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +213
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +41
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +127
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +352
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +266
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +33
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +386
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +63
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance

**EDIT** Just to elaborate on what I've tried:

- Restarting VS
- Restarting local and remote IIS
- Rebooting Windows Server
- Restarting SQL Server
- Checking the query in LINQPad (it works)
- Deleting the edmx Model and recreating it from scratch

Comment: did you capture `InnerException`?

Comment: This happens to me(almost all the time) when i kept a connection idle in ssms for a long time

Comment: @techspider The InnerException is the Transport-Level error exception. The transport-level error's innerexception is empty however

Comment: @TheGameiswar Any way to check for idle connection is ssms? I've rebooted Windows Server, restarted SQL Server, restarted IIS but nothing seems to make a difference

Comment: I am just saying a possibility of connection opened for a long time,long running query..Try updating statistics involved too

Comment: add this code to get `InnerException`; `catch (DbEntityValidationException ex){ foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }`

Comment: @techspider the exception thrown is `System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException`

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962927/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server)?

Comment: @techspider Yeah, I did. No luck. I even checked the error logs in SSMS, no errors