# Entity Framework SaveChanges throws error in docker container

Tags: entity-framework, docker, asp.net-core

We recently moved a .net project to .net core and have it running in a docker container.  Since doing so I've been getting an occasional error from entity framework when saving changes on a new entity.  In none of the cases does the entity have any related objects.  It's just creating a new single record in the database.

The error message unfortunately doesn't make much sense to me and I'm not sure where to begin looking.  Since it didn't do this before I'm wondering if it's somehow tied to being in a docker container or the move to .net core.  The error message is...

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level
>   error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider:
>   TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, UInt32 error) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[]
>   buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName,
>   TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout,
>   SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest
>   transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso,
>   SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest
>   transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso,
>   SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   iso, String transactionName) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransactionWithNoPreconditions(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2
>   parameters) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1
>   commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entries) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entriesToSave) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges() at
>   TEAPI.Domain.Data.Repositories.EventLogRepository.LogEvent(EventLogEvent
>   eventLogEvent) in
>   /home/web/buildAgent/work/35649df7ceb7c251/src/TEAPI.Domain/Data/Repositories/EventLogRepository.cs:line
>   52 at TEAPI.Controllers.EventLogController.LogSalesEvent() in
>   /home/web/buildAgent/work/35649df7ceb7c251/src/TEAPI/Controllers/EventLogController.cs:line
>   27 at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.b__0(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters) at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at TEAPI.Middleware.ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   in
>   /home/web/buildAgent/work/35649df7ceb7c251/src/TEAPI/Middleware/ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs:line
>   26 ClientConnectionId:72a861d4-e94c-4175-9249-bdca4a2b83a0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962927/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server)

Comment: Is the database in docker?

Comment: No.  After discussing with one of our system admin guys he thinks it's related to our load balancer.  I've made some updates based on that and so far so good.

Comment: @geoffswartz, hi, I have same issue with my application. Can you tell me how you fix it?

Comment: @sepulka And did you ever find a solution? :)

Comment: @Wiizl, yes. It isn't connected with docker. Sometimes my sql server reject connections. Probably because it hosted on same server with our application and app can take a lot of resources sometime. I add strategy that retry refused connections. Look at my changes you can here https://pastebin.com/uax7M4kM